# differing treatment of vertical tabs by different Perls

Tags: perl

I have two Perl programs that use identical libraries to process documents. They are installed on two different servers, and one runs Perl 5.12 while the other runs Perl 5.18.

Right now I am feeding the same files as input to both, so I can diff the output to make sure they match. I got hundreds of identical matches. They're normally processing UTF-8 files, and I've taken care to handle that encoding correctly.

Today they both received a binary file, and for the first time I saw a difference. I determined that one program (the one running Perl 5.18) stripped vertical tabs from the content of the file before outputting it, while the other program did not.

I could just write this off as not supporting binary files, but it still bothers me that they are different. I looked into the library doing the processing, and it contains this line (it will process every line in the file this way):

```
$line =~ s/\s//g;
```

Is it possible that one of the Perls thinks vertical tabs are spaces, while the other does not? How would I check that? Anything else you think I should look into?

Answer (score 7):

Since 5.18, [vertical tabs are considered whitespace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#Vertical-tabs-are-now-whitespace).

> No one could recall why `\s` didn't match `\cK`, the vertical tab. Now it does. Given the extreme rarity of that character, very little breakage is expected. That said, here's what it means:
>
> `\s` in a regex now matches a vertical tab in all circumstances.
>
> Literal vertical tabs in a regex literal are ignored when the `/x` modifier is used.
>
> Leading vertical tabs, alone or mixed with other whitespace, are now ignored when interpreting a string as a number. For example:
>
> ```
> $dec = " \cK \t 123";
> $hex = " \cK \t 0xF";
> say 0 + $dec;   # was 0 with warning, now 123
> say int $dec;   # was 0, now 123
> say oct $hex;   # was 0, now  15
> ```

This brings Perl in line with [Unicode](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropList.txt), which considers U+000B LINE TABULATION aka VERTICAL TABULATION aka VT a `White_Space` character.

---

You can get back the old behaviour by replacing `\s` with `[^\S\x0B]`.

Also worth considering is `\h`, which matches only horizontal whitespace characters.

```
U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION        Matched by \s & \h
U+000A LINE FEED                   Matched by \s & \v
U+000B LINE TABULATION             Matched by \s & \v
U+000C FORM FEED                   Matched by \s & \v
U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN             Matched by \s & \v
U+0020 SPACE                       Matched by \s & \h
U+0085 NEXT LINE                   Matched by \s & \v
U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE              Matched by \s & \h
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK            Matched by \s & \h
U+2000 EN QUAD                     Matched by \s & \h
U+2001 EM QUAD                     Matched by \s & \h
U+2002 EN SPACE                    Matched by \s & \h
U+2003 EM SPACE                    Matched by \s & \h
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE          Matched by \s & \h
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE           Matched by \s & \h
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE            Matched by \s & \h
U+2007 FIGURE SPACE                Matched by \s & \h
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE           Matched by \s & \h
U+2009 THIN SPACE                  Matched by \s & \h
U+200A HAIR SPACE                  Matched by \s & \h
U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR              Matched by \s & \v
U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR         Matched by \s & \v
U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE       Matched by \s & \h
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE   Matched by \s & \h
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE           Matched by \s & \h
```